# Get current element's classes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
​<button id="test" class="example whatever">Show classes</button>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

$('button').click(function(){
  var classes = $(this).attr('class');
  alert(classes);
});​
```

The above code returns the content of the `class` attribute. How can I get it to return the classes formatted?

For instance, in this case, I want the variable `classes` to have a value of `.example.whatever` instead of `example whatever`.

I've searched and the only solution that seemed to be provided is the code I demonstrated above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm really very uneasy about this, since replacing spaces with periods will give the representation of stacked classes, when the classes aren't really stacked, but here you go:

```
// class="foo bar fiz buz" -> .foo.bar.fiz.buz
this.className.replace( /^|\s/g , "." );
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/awitef/edit#javascript,html

Comment: `this.className.trim().replace(/(^|\s+)(?=\w)/g , '.');` also takes care of the empty String, leading or trailing whitespaces, and multiple whitespaces between classes

Answer (score 1):

```
$('button').click(function(){
  var classes = $(this).attr('class');
  alert("." + classes.split(" ").join(".") );
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wxDEh/3/